# Hide fields from Contact Layout

Tags: page-layout, contact

Contact OWD is "Public Read Only", we have requirement to hide phone and email field from detail page layout.

how to achieve this?

Comment: What Salesforce edition do you use? Do you want to hide from all users or just some? Have you looked at using field level security: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_fls.htm ?

Comment: thanks for quick reply, we want only owner and those who has read/write access for contact reacord can edit and fill these fields but no one can see on detail page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I grant different field-level security based on record ownership?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/777/can-i-grant-different-field-level-security-based-on-record-ownership)